# Postgresql error: function "json_to_recordset(text) doesn't exist"

Tags: sql, postgresql

**I create this function:**

```
-- Function: public.proc_rebate2reachrebateinsert(text)

-- DROP FUNCTION public.proc_rebate2reachrebateinsert(text);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.proc_rebate2reachrebateinsert(paramstr text)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$

DECLARE
v_sql1 text;
v_sql2 text;
v_sql3 text;
v_sql4 text;
s_contract_no text;
v_contract_no character varying;
v_line_no integer; 
v_history_no integer;                                   
v_f_sin integer;                                        
v_p_typeid integer;                                 
v_compare_typeid integer;   
v_val_typeid integer;                                       
v_goal_val numeric;
v_count_typeid integer; 
v_f_pb_ignore integer;
v_all_products integer;
v_judge_typeid integer;                                                         
v_ins_user_id integer;
v_upd_user_id integer;
v_upd_user_name character varying;
v_reach_condition_array text;
v_dept_category_jan_array text;
v_sku_appoint text;
v_series_appoint text;

in_obj text;
objjson json;
insertjson json;
begin

    insertJson=paramStr::json;
    s_contract_no=(select cast(json_extract_path(insertJson,'contract_no') as text));
    v_line_no=to_number((select cast(json_extract_path(insertJson,'line_no') as text)),'000000000000000000');
    v_history_no=to_number((select cast(json_extract_path(insertJson,'history_no') as text)),'000000000000000000');
    v_p_typeid=to_number((select cast(json_extract_path(insertJson,'p_typeid') as text)),'000000000000000000');
    v_compare_typeid=to_number((select cast(json_extract_path(insertJson,'compare_typeid') as text)),'000000000000000000');
    v_val_typeid=to_number((select cast(json_extract_path(insertJson,'val_typeid') as text)),'000000000000000000');                                     
    v_goal_val=to_number((select cast(json_extract_path(insertJson,'goal_val') as text)),'000000000000000000'); 
    v_count_typeid=to_number((select cast(json_extract_path(insertJson,'count_typeid') as text)),'000000000000000000');
    v_judge_typeid=to_number((select cast(json_extract_path(insertJson,'judge_typeid') as text)),'000000000000000000'); 
    select json_extract_path(insertJson,'reach_condition_array') into v_reach_condition_array;
    if v_p_typeid='1' then
        select json_extract_path(insertJson,'dept_category_jan_array') into v_dept_category_jan_array;
    elsif v_p_typeid='2' then 
        select json_extract_path(insertJson,'sku_appoint') into v_sku_appoint;
    elsif v_p_typeid='3' then 
        select json_extract_path(insertJson,'series_appoint') into v_series_appoint;    
    end if;  
v_ins_user_id=to_number((select cast(json_extract_path(insertJson,'ins_user_id') as text)),'000000000000000000');
    v_upd_user_id=to_number((select cast(json_extract_path(insertJson,'upd_user_id') as text)),'000000000000000000');
    v_upd_user_name=replace((select cast(json_extract_path(insertJson,'upd_user_name') as character varying)),'"','');

    if (s_contract_no <> '""') then
        v_contract_no=replace((select cast(json_extract_path(insertJson,'contract_no') as character varying)),'"','');
        v_history_no=to_number((select cast(json_extract_path(insertJson,'history_no') as text)),'000000000000000000');

        if exists(select * from public.rebatesys_mstcontract  where contract_no=v_contract_no and history_no=v_history_no and line_no=v_line_no) then
            v_f_sin=(select f_sin from public.rebatesys_00mstcontract  where contract_no=v_contract_no and history_no=v_history_no and line_no=v_line_no);
            if (v_f_sin=1) then
                UPDATE public.rebatesys_mstcontract SET  f_sin=0 WHERE contract_no=v_contract_no and history_no=v_history_no and line_no=v_line_no;
                UPDATE public.rebatesys_mstcontractdetail SET  f_sin=0 WHERE contract_no=v_contract_no and history_no=v_history_no and line_no=v_line_no;
                UPDATE public.rebatesys_mstcontractreward SET  f_sin=0 WHERE contract_no=v_contract_no and history_no=v_history_no and line_no=v_line_no;
                v_history_no=v_history_no+1;
            end if;
        end if;   
    end if;
    v_sql1 :='
            INSERT INTO public.rebatesys_mstcontract(
            head, contract_no, history_no, f_sin, line_no, p_typeid,compare_typeid,val_typeid,goal_val,count_typeid,f_pb_ignore,                                        
            f_del,ins_date,ins_time,ins_user_id,ins_func_id,ins_ope_id,upd_date,upd_time,upd_user_id,upd_func_id,upd_ope_id)
        VALUES (0, '''||v_contract_no||''', '||v_history_no||',1, '||v_line_no||', '||v_p_typeid||', 
            '||v_compare_typeid||', '||v_val_typeid||', '||v_goal_val||','||v_count_typeid||','||v_f_pb_ignore||',
            0, current_date, current_time, '||v_ins_user_id||', 0, 0,
            current_date,current_time,'||v_upd_user_id||',0, 0);
    ';      

    EXECUTE v_sql1;
    RAISE NOTICE 'v_dept_category_jan_array IS : %', v_dept_category_jan_array;
    if v_p_typeid='1' then

        insert into public.rebatesys_mstcontractdetail(head,contract_no,history_no,f_sin,line_no,
        f_del,ins_date,ins_time,ins_user_id,ins_func_id,ins_ope_id,upd_date,upd_time,upd_user_id,upd_func_id,upd_ope_id,
        s_line_no,departmentcd,catagorycd,jan,seriescd,f_exclude)
        select 0,v_contract_no,v_history_no,1,v_line_no,
             0, current_date, current_time, v_ins_user_id, 0, 0, current_date,current_time,v_upd_user_id,0, 0,
         down_s_line_no,deptCD,categoryCD,singleJan,seriesJan,fExclude from json_to_recordset(''''||v_dept_category_jan_array||'''') 
         as x(s_line_no int, deptCD int,categoryCD int,singleJan int,seriesJan int,fExclude int);

    end if;
  END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION public.proc_rebate2reachrebateinsert(text)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

After create this function,I use:

```
 select * from public.proc_rebate2reachrebateinsert('{
        "contract_no":"1001",
        "line_no":"1",
        "history_no":0,
        "p_typeid":"1",
        "compare_typeid":1,
        "val_typeid":"2",
        "goal_val":783.11,
        "count_typeid":1,
        "f_pb_ignore":0,
        "all_products":0,
        "judge_typeid":"1",
        "ins_user_id":1,
        "upd_user_id":1,

    "reach_condition_array":[
        {
            "up_s_line_no":1,
            "t_from":.1,
            "t_to":30.1,
            "rebate":11
        },
        {
            "up_s_line_no":2,
            "t_from":30.1,
            "t_to":40.6,
            "rebate":22.5
        }

    ],
    "dept_category_jan_array":[
        {
            "down_s_line_no":1,
            "deptCD":30,
            "categoryCD":2,
            "singleJan":1,
            "seriesJan":0,
            "fExclude":0
        },
        {
            "down_s_line_no":2,
            "deptCD":34,
            "categoryCD":1,
            "singleJan":0,
            "seriesJan":0,
            "fExclude":0
        }

    ]
}')
```

to test this function,but the error message is:

`ERROR:  function json_to_recordset(text) doesn't exist`
`LINE 6: ...ptCD,categoryCD,singleJan,seriesJan,fExclude from json_to_re...`

How to fix it ?

Answer (score 2):

The variable holding your JSON array is already declared as a string, so you don't need to add extra quotes. It is still perceived as text, so you would need to indicate it is a json structure by using `::json`

```
select [...] 
from json_to_recordset(v_dept_category_jan_array::json) 
  as x(s_line_no int, deptCD int,categoryCD int,singleJan int,seriesJan int,fExclude int);
```

Let's note that you might have to change your json variable names, as they are case sensitive. For example, you  have the data `"deptCD":30` but you declare the column as `deptCD int`, so they won't match. You can change your column to keep the casing `"deptCD" int` or make is lower case in the JSON `"deptcd":30`. The same would occur if you rename the column: `s_line_no` will always be empty since there is no matching entry in the JSON - it is `down_s_line_no`.

Comment: When I use RAISE NOTICE 'v_dept_category_jan_array IS : %', v_dept_category_jan_array;
The output is  a  array like this:v_dept_category_jan_array IS : [
        {
            "down_s_line_no":1,
            "deptCD":30,
            "categoryCD":2,
            "singleJan":1,
            "seriesJan":0,
            "fExclude":0
        },
        {
            "down_s_line_no":2,
            "deptCD":34,
            "categoryCD":1,
            "singleJan":0,
            "seriesJan":0,
            "fExclude":0
        }]
So it is an array,isn't is?